# How to encrypt the content of a form (including attachments)

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, gpgpu, pgp

Let's say I have a form with text boxes and possibly attachments, I'd like to secure the content, including the attachments, by encrypting them and then sending them to another party that would decrypt and then read them.

I looked into encryption standards such as PGP that I can use. But I would like to know what is the best way to approach this problem.

What I have in mind now is: Converting the Form to a JSON File, adding this file and the attachements to a Zip file, convert it to a binary then encrypt it and do the opposite on the other side.

Am I approaching the problem in the right way, or is there any other efficient ways that I can use? 
I'll be using either Java or Javascript to do this.

Comment: encryption in the browser? What's wrong with using `https`?

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem, what are you trying to achieve exactly? HTTPS should be sufficient for most use cases

Comment: Yes preferably in the browser

Comment: encryption in the browser is fundamentally flawed, unless you get some of the encryption vectors externally - the whole world can see javascript in a web page, and therefore your encryption algorithm

Comment: @JaromandaX Asymmetric encryption is a solution, but it still makes you vulernable to MITM